# I'm confused about service in Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I have a big program that has many forms and works with database, etc. I have an alarm as a part of my program. When I fire the alarm and clean the memory (in task manager) after 10-20 seconds the alarm fires an event (even if time has not yet arrived). If I run the alarm as Independent Software - it runs perfect!

Could it be that alarm can't be a part of program?  Or what can be the problem?

This is how I work with the alarm:

```
    MY_Day=1;
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyService.this, MyAlarmService.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MyService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, MY_Houre);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, MY_Minute);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Total_Time = MY_Day * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), Total_Time, 
pendingIntent);
```

and this my service:

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service {
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MyEvent",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
   LinearLayout toastView = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
   ImageView imageCodeProject = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
   imageCodeProject.setImageResource(R.drawable.koko);
   toastView.addView(imageCodeProject, 0);
   toast.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Re-consider your code and read [Vogella Service Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) for more information about service.